# Boost geometry and STL

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-geometry

How to create a boost geometry polygon using std::vector? For example

```
    typedef double coordinate_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<coordinate_type> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

    boost::geometry::model::linestring<point> test_data;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)", test_data);
```

The above works well. Let us assume that I have polygon points in two vectors as follows:

```
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(3);
    y.push_back(2);
    y.push_back(4);
```

How can I create the data

```
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4)", test_data);
```

Similarly, if I have an intersect points, for example:

```
    std::deque<polygon> output;
    boost::geometry::intersection(test1, test2, output);
    BOOST_FOREACH(polygon const& p, output)
    {
        std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(p) << std::endl;
    }
```

How can I get the data from 'p' into the vectors x,y?

I will appreciate the help and guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it :

```
typedef double coordinate_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<coordinate_type> point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;

point p1(1,3);
point p2(2,4);

polygon my_polygon = { p1, p2 };

std::cout << boost::geometry::wkt(p) << std::endl;
```

You can do the same by just constructing your points from your vectors.